# flask - easy application but with error 404 not found

Tags: flask, http-status-code-404, flask-sqlalchemy

I am starting with flask, I went through many tutorials and everything worked. But I started my own application and I get only error 404 not found.

Configuration of my apache virtual server is:

```
<VirtualHost domain:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@domain
   ServerName domain
   ServerAlias domain *.domain

   WSGIDaemonProcess test user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www-py/domain
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www-py/domain/domain.wsgi

 <Directory /var/www-py/domain>
    WSGIProcessGroup test
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

domain.wsgi:

```
import sys, os

current_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(current_dir)
from domain import app as application
```

domain/__init__.py

```
import os, sys
from flask import Flask
from datetime import *
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug=True
app.secret_key = 'mysecretkey'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

domain/views/index.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
abort, render_template, flash

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')
```

That's all and easy application. Problem is that all applications which I tried was written in one file. Now I am trying to separated to classify it into files to be easier to manage bigger project.
Please could you help me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. In `views/index.py` you don't actually define `app`, so that will result in a `NameError` if you ever actually import `views.index`.
2. In `__init__.py` you never import `views.index` so your route never gets added to the `Flask.url_routes` map.

You have two options:

1. You can take the circular imports way out, as specified in the docs:

   ```
   # views.index
   from flask import render_template
   from domain import app

   @app.route("/")
   def index():
       return render_template("index.html")

   # __init__.py

   # ... snip ...
   db = SQLAlchemy(app)

   # View imports need to be at the bottom
   # to ensure that we don't run into problems 
   # with partially constructed dependencies
   # as this is a circular import
   # (__init__ imports views.index which imports __init__ which imports views.index ...)
   from views import index
   ```
2. You can pull the creation of `app` into a separate file and avoid circular imports entirely:

   ```
   # NEW: infrastructure.py
   from flask import Flask
   from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

   app = Flask("domain")
   db = SQLAlchemy(app)

   # views.index
   from domain.infrastructure import app

   # NEW: app.py
   from domain.infrastructure import app
   import domain.views.index

   # __init__.py
   # is now empty
   ```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried your second solution, it seem to be more clear for large applications. But it doesn't work. At now I received error "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable". Do you know what it can mean?

Comment: @user1743947 - generally it means that the symbol you are looking at is a module, not a callable object.  Can you post the entire stack trace in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need import views.index in domain/**init**.py, and add "from domain import app" in index.py. Otherwise it cannot find app